# Declare a generic class in scala without square brackets

Tags: scala, scala-generics

When reading [this article](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2015/06/28/put-your-writes-where-your-master-is-compile-time-restriction-of-slick-effect-types.html) I came to the following syntax:

```
implicit val slaveCanRead: Slave HasPrivilege Read = null
```

The author says:

> Also, please not that `Slave HasPrivilege Read` is just another notation for `HasPrivilege[Slave, Read]`

Keeping the example in basic scala, the example could also be

```
val foo: Map[String, Long] = Map()
val bar: String Map Long = Map()
```

I was looking for some documentation/articles that would explain this syntax but could not find any. Can someone point to the language feature which allows this syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s really just as simple as `T1 TCon T2 = TCon[T1, T2]`. It’s [section 3.2.8 of the language specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types).

> ```
> InfixType ::= CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
> ```

If the infix type ends with `:` it is right associative, and otherwise it is left associative, just like methods, and mixing fixities is an error without parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [infix type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types). Thus

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = ...
```

is actually equivalent to

```
val map: String Map Int = ...
```

This is especially useful for the `Function` type so you can write

```
val f: Int => Int = ...
```

instead of

```
val f: Function[Int, Int] = ...
```